# Restricting a two character string in a REGEX in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I am using this condition in my script

```
    WHERE colA NOT LIKE '2[6-9]{2}'
```

so it returns true for the 2 character strings 26,27,28,29 but a three character string like 267 is also returning true. How can I amend this so only the two character strings return true please?

Comment: SQL Server does not support regular expressions.

Comment: You are doing a `not like` so it should be returning *false* for 26, in a database that supports that form of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the {2}.  What you have is, in plain English, "match anything that starts with a 2, then has 2 characters between 6 and 9."  You need it to be "match anything with a 2, then one character between 6 and 9."